# Border-box style wont work

Tags: html, css

Please, see this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xg6SJ/2/

Why text `jumps`?
Why borders on `hover` expands menu's div?

```
*, *:before, *:after 
{
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box; 
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; 
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

div
{
    height: 100px;
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: #eee;
}

ul
{
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

li
{
    display: block;
    float: left;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}

li > a
{
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 20px;
    display: table-cell;
    height: 100px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding: 0 18px;
}

li:hover
{
    border-top: 2px red solid;
    border-bottom: 2px red solid;
    background-color: #ddd;
}


<div>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">sdfdf</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">sdfdf</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">sdfdf</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">sdfdf</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `li` doesn't have a fixed height. If you set the height of the `li` to `100px` the border is put inside the element on hover.

To prevent the text from jumping you can remove the additional height added by the borders from the `a` like this:

```
li:hover > a {
    height: 96px; /* 100 - (border-top + border-bottom) */
}
```

Or you can add a transparent border and a fixed height to the `li` ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xg6SJ/6/)).

```
li {
    ...
    border-top: 2px transparent solid;
    border-bottom: 2px transparent solid;
    height: 100px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the border is added to the div on hover only. So on hovering, the div's height is expanded. If you added `border-top: 2px grey` to the `li` (in 'unhovered' state) , you won't have that jumping effect anymore.

Check the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xg6SJ/3/

Comment: Why div's height is expanded? Isn't `border-box` style tell that dimensions *must* remain in initial sizes?

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/
quote from this link `The border and padding values moved inward, cutting into the width/height of the box rather than expanding it. `

Comment: The `li` doesn't have a fixed `height`. If you set the height of the `li` to `100px` the border is put inside the element on hover.

Comment: Thanks @Ex-iT. But now, how to prevent text from `jumping` on hover?

Answer (score 0):

```
li
{
    display: block;
    float: left;
    box-sizing:content-box;
}
```

Because, border-box ... The width and height properties include the padding and border, but not the margin. content-box ...This is the default style as specified by the CSS standard. The width and height properties are measured including only the content, but not the border, margin, or padding.

You are adding 2px to top on bottom on hover which where not their before.

Or add the two pixels of border to li and have the border be the same as the background until you hover.

```
li
{
    display: block;
    float: left;
    border-top: 2px #eee; solid;
}
```